# On the probability of a collision in RFO-rCTR

Tags: chosen-plaintext-attack, ctr

My slides show that assuming a polynomial number $q(n)$ of blocks have been encrypted by a random function oracle in the context of a CPA-game, the probability of having a collision in the input to the oracle is bounded by $\frac{q(n)^2}{2^{l(n)}}$ (cfr. Katz and Lidell, 2nd edition pages 93-94).

Then I am proposed the following: assuming that in total $e(n)$ messages are encrypted each consisting of at most $s(n)$ blocks then the probability of a collission in the input is bounded by $\frac{e(n)^2s(n)}{2^{l(n)}}$.

Is this a typo? Why are we dropping the square from $s(n)$?

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iUs3QWHS9o2tPlC0TrklaUsEgYLApz0w/view?usp=sharing) you may see the slides I refer to (see slide 18 and 19)

Comment: Read it as number of messages $e$ times number of message blocks $e\cdot s$.  Note that the initial counter is chosen randomly.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage is a good way to see it, but how do I deduce the inequality from the given fact?

Comment: Blocks within the same message never collide. So to determine the number of possible collisions you have a sum of the form $\sum_{i=1}^{e(n)} (i - 1) s(n) = s(n) {e(n) \choose 2} \le s(n) e(n)^2$.

Comment: @SamuelNeves perfect! that is the answer. i see that it is reasonable to assume that blocks within the same message never collide, they could in principle, for instance in the rCTR mode if $s(n) > 2^{l(n)}$ but of course this is not the case in practice. You may want to post your comment as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key idea here is the blocks within the same message do not collide—message $1$ will have no possible block collisions, message $2$ can collide with the message $1$'s $s(n)$ blocks, message $i$ can collide with message $i-1$'s $s(n)$ blocks or message $i-2$'s $s(n)$ blocks, etc.

In other words, the number of possibly colliding block combinations is given by
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{e(n)} (i - 1)s(n)\,,
$$
which simplifies to $s(n) {e(n) \choose 2}$. We turn this into a probability $$ \frac{s(n){e(n) \choose 2}}{2^{l(n)}} \le \frac{s(n)e(n)^2}{2^{l(n)}}\,.$$